# SQL Server 2008 insert into table using loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I want to insert records in a table with certain values which I got from a `SELECT` query on other other tables.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 c.ContaId
FROM FastGroupe fg
INNER JOIN FastParticipant fp 
    ON fg.FastGroupeId = fp.FastGroupeId
INNER JOIN Participant p
    ON fp.ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId
INNER JOIN Contact c
    ON p.ContaId = c.ContaId
WHERE FastGroupeName like '%Group%'
```

I want to use the IDs I get from this query to insert in another table `Member` which use `ContaId` as a foreign key.

I want to use a `WHILE` loop, but I don't know the number of records I will get from the `SELECT` query.

So, is there a workaround for this problem.

EDIT

This is the table `Member`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Request](
[MemberId] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ContaId] int NOT NULL,
[PromoId] int NOT NULL
);
```

The `PromoId` is a non null column, but I want to put the same value for all the records I am about to create.

The `Member` records have to be like this

```
 MemberId = Automatic,
 ContaId = // one of the query results,
 PromoId = 91
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to use the IDs I get from this query to insert in another table
>   Member which use ContaId as a foreign key.

You can use [**`INSERT INTO .. SELECT`**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/10/sql-server-use-insert-into-select-instead-of-cursor/) instead of cursors and while loops like so:

```
INSERT INTO Member(ContaId)
SELECT TOP 1000 c.ContaId
FROM FastGroupe fg
INNER JOIN FastParticipant fp 
    ON fg.FastGroupeId = fp.FastGroupeId
INNER JOIN Participant p
    ON fp.ParticipantId = p.ParticipantId
INNER JOIN Contact c
    ON p.ContaId = c.ContaId
WHERE FastGroupeName like '%Group%'
```

**Update:** Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Member(ContaId, PromoId)
SELECT TOP 1000 c.ContaId, 91 AS PromoId
FROM FastGroupe fg
...
```

This will insert the same value `91` for the `PromoId` for all the 1000 records. And since the `MemberId` is set to be automatic, just ignore it in the columns' list and it will get an automatic value.

Comment: wow so simple, but in the table `Member`, I have other columns which don't come from the `SELECT` query. Will that be a problem ?

Comment: @the_ruby_racer, It will be a problem, because the select statement will give you 1000 ids, for the other columns which don't come from the select query. How did you will get them? You have to put them by somehow within this select statment. By `JOIN` or `UNION`. Can you please explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You need only to make sure that number of columns match the selected data in the subquery

the Syntax is like this:

```
Insert into YourTable(calumn1, column2, ..., columnN) 
values (Select (calumn1, column2, ..., columnN) from ... ) // The Subquery
```

Comment: in the table Member, I have other columns which don't come from the SELECT query. Will that be a problem ?

Comment: IT depends if these are Not Nullabel or Constraint Columns you will have to decide what values get there. Otherwise this will be no problem you will have only to write as much columns after Insert as much as you select in the Subquery